# Date Manipulation in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have site that was migrated from Rails 2.2.2 to Rails 3.2.1.

I am now seeing weird date issues related to one custom method call.

I have a method that returns a given date in the format MM/DD/YYYY

```
 def clean_date date
    return "00/00/00" if !date or date == ""
    return date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") if date.class.to_s == "Date"
    return Date.parse(date).strftime("%m/%d/%Y") # assume it's a string
  end
```

After I moved to Rails 3, it stopped returning the correctly formatted date. It is now returning a MySQL type of date format

```
>>> SHIP DATE BEFORE CLEAN: 12/24/2013
>>> SHIP DATE AFTER CLEAN: 2013-12-24
```

**The Calling Controller**

```
require 'date'

[...]

 ## In: 12/24/2013
 existing_ship_date = clean_date(poi.ship_date)
 ## Out: 2013-12-24
 ## Should always return: 12/24/2013
```

How can I fix this method such that it works with Rails 3.2.1?

Thanks for looking

Comment: I don't see why this function would return the date in that format. Which version of Ruby are you using? What is the data type of poi.ship_date? Finally, which return statement in the function is being executed? Perhaps put some logging statements in the function so that we know which branch the function is being taken.

Comment: poi.ship_date is a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD so the  Date.parse(date).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")  was not changing the input value  to MM/DD/YYYY; it was just passing it through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an alternative date parser. I have found a lot of value from this gem:

https://github.com/mojombo/chronic

Answer (score 0):

1.Create this file:

`rails_app_root_directory/config/initializers/date_formats.rb`

2.Put your date format in there:

`Date::DATE_FORMATS[:ship_date] = "%m/%d/%Y"`

3.In your controller use it as needed to format your Date objects:

`Date.today.to_formatted_s(:ship_date)`

Output: "05/07/2013"

4.Don't forget to restart rails!

Comment: Thanks for this. Before I saw your solution, I went with  the gem Chronic as it plugs right into the method call so less code to maintain which is always a good thing.